# "This app isn't verified" warning shows for an app that doesn't require verification

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

We have a web app that only uses the email, profile, openid, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file API scopes, none of which are listed as being restricted or sensitive. However, our OAuth Consent Screen flow is still taking the user to the "This app is unverified" message.

When we submitted the app for verification,we received a message back saying :

"Based on the type of request you've submitted you can skip the verification process if your app does not need to display an icon. If you decide to skip the verification process, it won't impact the existing functionality of your app, as long as the scopes used by your project don't change. However, if your app is being verified as a captive portal you must complete the verification process."

How can I remove app logo from Oauth consent screen ?

Why are we receiving an "unverified app" message for an app with no sensitive/restricted scopes? How do we keep our customers from getting that error message?

Comment: There is a [documentation](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en) which provides information about unverified apps and there is also [this](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en) FAQ documentation about OAuth API verification. You can find a lot of information about your issue. Most probably I believe that you have to go through the verification process.